# Update R Commands from Bash

Tags: r, bash

My problem is simple: is there a way to update R packages from the BASH command line? Something like `r cmd "update.packages(ask=FALSE)"`, except one that works?

Thanks.

Comment: can't you just put the `update.packages` line in an R script and use R CMD BATCH myUpdateScript.R?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Rscript` with `-e` option to run a specific expression and just change your repos as necessary:

```
Rscript -e "update.packages(ask=F, repos='http://r-forge.r-project.org')"
```